# Ruby simply role codotion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On ruby I use below to determine the role.

```
if current_user.try(:admin?) or current_user.try(:superuser?)
```

Can it simplify like (this example not work).

```
if current_user.try(:admin?||:superuser?)
```

**Edit:**

Can i use helper to simplify it? like

```
has_role([:admin?,:superuser?])
```

My User model has enum for the role

```
enum role: [:user, :admin, :superuser]
```

Comment: If you have lots of roles, perhaps look at something like RoleModel gem to define the roles as opposed to set of boolean flags.  Makes it easier to say something like if current_user.has_any_role?( :admin, :realm_admin, :system_admin)

Comment: Perhaps `current_user && [:admin?, :superuser?].any? { |role| current_user.send(role) }`?

Comment: `or` is not equivalent to `||` in Ruby. You should not be using it for boolean logic unless you explicitly  need it.

Comment: You might want to consider turning your access control logic around a bit. Instead of asking if they're an admin  or superuser, why not ask if they can do task X and let the implementation of `can_X?` be a simple `admin? || superuser?`?

Comment: Hi Doon, i am looking something your said. i try to use rolify but is it to heavy.

Answer (score 1):

You can not simplify it like this, because `try` method gets only 1 argument. It is the simplest way.
`:admin?||:superuser?` returns `:admin` in all cases, because in Ruby, if the left argument of `||` operator true (not nil of false), it will return.
So, in your second instance, you will always try to call `admin?` method on `current_user`

```
1 || false 
#=> 1
1 || 2
#=> 1
:admin? || :current_user
#=> :admin?
```